# Prove that the ring of formal power series over a field is an UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The problem is from Artin.

> Prove that the ring $\mathbb{R}[[t]]$ of formal power series given by $p(t)=a_0 + a_1 t+ a_2 t^2 + \cdots$ is an UFD.

I have no idea how to do this. From the couple of things that I know about UFDs is that I could show that every irreducible element is prime, or I could show that every chain of ideals terminates. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Show that each ideal $\neq 0$ has the form $\mathfrak a = t^k\mathbb R[[t]] $.

Comment: Excellent answer. In acronyms : every PID is a UFD.

Comment: @Hagen: Thanks! Cud you help me with a similar question, where I have to show that the ring of Laurent polynomials is a principal ideal domain?

Comment: @Georges: We don't need to use this fact. From the ideal structure one can immediately check UFD, with the only prime element $t$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: How can you say t is the only prime element?

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac Every power series $a_0+a_1t+\dots$ with $a_0\ne0$ is invertible in $\mathbb{R}[[t]]$; this should answer both your two new questions.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for the help. I can see how your statement helps me with the second question. But, I still have no idea how to do the first one. In a Laurent polynomial, how do I prove t is an irreducible element? Is this what you expect me to that? But how would it prove that ring of laurent polynomials in a PID?

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac In the ring of Laurent series, $t$ is *not* an irreducible element because it's invertible. What are the noninvertible elements in the ring of Laurent series?

Comment: @egreg: I don't know. :(. After thinking about it a lot, I am getting all elements are invertible i.e. it is a field, which is clearly absurd. What is wrong in this: For a laurent polynomial, I can multiply by the lowest power, to convert it to a the usual polynomial in t, with a constant element. The laurent polynomial is over a field according to the question, and I can take it out. Each of these polynomials has an inverse. Isn't it a field then? :(

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac The ring of Laurent series *is* a field: what's absurd about this? So it's trivially a UFD.

Comment: @egreg: OP was asking about Laurent _polynomials_, not series. $\Bbb R[x,x^{-1}]$ is an UFD because it is a localisation of the UFD $\Bbb R[x]$.